# Recommend a Node.js tech stack/architecture for a modern web app?

Tags: node.js

Can anyone point to me on what techs/architecture I need to learn in Node.js in order to build a picture & location based web app?(kind of like a mesh of twitter+foursquare)

From what I read the following are considered popular and do I need to learn them all? Anything else I am missing from the picture?

- OS = Ubuntu, Gentoo or Debian
- db = [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org)
- template = [Jade](http://jade-lang.com)
- css = [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/)
- framework = [Express](http://expressjs.com/)
- code= [coffeescript](http://www.coffeescript.org/)
- networking = [socket.io](http://www.socket.io/)
- mcv structure = [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)
- authentication = [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/)
- ide = [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) or [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

Comment: You are aware that using these technologies along won't do anything magical for you?

Comment: Just need to know what to learn in order to start..

Comment: How about starting in order to learn what you need to know? I doubt that the answers to this question will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds good.

You could also add stylus for CSS pre-processing and passport npm package to ease your authentication process.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to checkout these node.js based frameworks (both written in coffescript)

- TowerJS (modelled after Ruby on Rails)

  - Homepage: http://towerjs.org/
  - Source: https://github.com/viatropos/tower
- Ace (modelled after sinatra)

  - Source https://github.com/maccman/ace

Comment: For ace: "Node >= v0.7.3" which means that you would have to use the dev version of Node rather than the released version.

Comment: "Ace" is a nightmare name for an application! Trying to do a search for references is pointless. As with most Node frameworks, documentation and useful examples are non-existent so it could only be recommended if you have plenty of time to figure it out for yourself.   Tower seems rather more mature though I've not yet tried it myself. It certainly has more documentation including a Google Group. I think it may be the one I try next. I've already tried Derby and SocketStream which are really not yet ready for significant project us due to missing elements and lack of documentation/examples.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the [Flatiron framework](http://flatironjs.com) - it is split into several modules, and you can pick and choose your favorite ones. The routing module, [Union](http://github.com/flatiron/union), is backwards compatible with Connect/Express.